# How to insert PHP in my Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found and adapted a php script that processes the content of a contact form and sends and/or display alerts that would appear on a Bootstrap 3 modal window.
I manage to make work my script and display my errors, as well as to display my modal onload with non php in it, but as soon as I try to include my php code into the modal to display the errors within the modal, nothing displays.

I tried many ways : PHP in HTML, HMTL in PHP… And no combination worked. This is where I arrived so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>My title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Squad theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="color/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
    <body>

<?php

      // Clean up the input values
      foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
         if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

         $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
      }

      // Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $message = $_POST["message"];

      // Test input values for errors
      $errors = array();
      if(strlen($name) < 2) {
         if(!$name) {
            $errors[] = "Vous devez indiquer votre nom.";
         } else {
            $errors[] = "Votre nom doit faire au moins deux caractères de long.";
         }
      }
      if(!$email) {
         $errors[] = "Vous devez renseigner votre email.";
      } else if(!validEmail($email)) {
         $errors[] = "Merci de fournir une adresse email valide.";
      }
      if(strlen($message) < 10) {
         if(!$message) {
            $errors[] = "Vous devez saisir votre message.";
         } else {
            $errors[] = "Merci de laisser un message d'au moins dix caractères de long.";
         }
      }
      if($errors) {
                     // Output errors and die with a failure message
                    $errortext = "";
                    foreach($errors as $error) {
                    $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
                    }
                    die("
                        <div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"fail-prompt\">
                          <div class=\"modal-dialog\">
                            <div class=\"modal-content\">
                              <div class=\"modal-header\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span></button>
                                <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Votre message n'a pas pu être envoyé.</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class=\"modal-body\">
                                 <p>Votre message n'a pas pu être envoyé</p>
                                 <ul>". $errortext ."</ul>
                              </div>
                              <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Retour vers le formulaire</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>");

            // Send the email
            $to = "myemail";
            $subject = "Contact Form: $name";
            $message = "$message";
            $headers = "From: $email";

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            // Die with a success message
            die("<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"fail-prompt\">
                  <div class=\"modal-dialog\">
                     <div class=\"modal-content\">
                     <div class=\"modal-header\">
                        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Message envoyé avec succès !</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class=\"modal-body\">
                        <p>Votre message a été envoyé avec succès !</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class=\"modal-footer\">
                        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Retour au site</button>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>");

            // A function that checks to see if
            // an email is valid
            function validEmail($email)
            {
               $isValid = true;
               $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
               if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
               {
                  $isValid = false;
               }
               else
               {
                  $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
                  $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
                  $localLen = strlen($local);
                  $domainLen = strlen($domain);
                  if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
                  {
                     // local part length exceeded
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
                  {
                     // domain part length exceeded
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
                  {
                     // local part starts or ends with '.'
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
                  {
                     // local part has two consecutive dots
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
                  {
                     // character not valid in domain part
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
                  {
                     // domain part has two consecutive dots
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
                  else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
                  {
                     // character not valid in local part unless 
                     // local part is quoted
                     if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
                         str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
                     {
                        $isValid = false;
                     }
                  }
                  if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
                  {
                     // domain not found in DNS
                     $isValid = false;
                  }
               }
               return $isValid;
            }
      ?>

</body>

        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Script-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#fail-prompt').modal('show');
            backdrop: 'static';
            keyboard: false;
        });
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the modal calling the php code with jquery:

This is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h2 style="color:#f68a26;font-weight:500;" align="left">Eventos y Noticias</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><div id="content-php"></div></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-overlay" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery script:

```
$("#icon_events_header").click(function(){
    $("#content-php").load("./admin/content/eventsContent.php");    
});
```

In the file you can manage all the action of the modal.

Hope works for you,

Answer (score 0):

PHP don't create a modal, because for lack includes of styles, js...
Recommended "create a modal" using ajax.